# Xaml фрагмент в C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Помогите перевести код из Xaml в C#, ну то есть чтобы дерево свойств и объектов создавалось динамически в canvas.

```
<Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="10">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathGeometry.Figures>
                    <PathFigureCollection>    
                        <PathFigure StartPoint="100,80">
                            <PathFigure.Segments>
                                <PathSegmentCollection>
                                    <PolyBezierSegment Points="90,200 140,200 160,200 180,200 430,190 430,280" />
                                </PathSegmentCollection>
                            </PathFigure.Segments>
                        </PathFigure>
                    </PathFigureCollection>
                </PathGeometry.Figures>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
```

Comment: Кажется кто-то только что спалился на двух аккаунтах :).

Comment: @andreycha это у меня один профиль на телефоне, а другой на компьютере :D

Comment: И зачем вам этот геморрой?

Comment: @andreycha с кодом или акком?

Comment: С аккаунтом ...

Comment: @andreycha я просто не знаю как удалить второй акк?

Comment: Ну то есть это не вопрос, а утверждение )

Comment: Так: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account Или забыть пароль и пользоваться одним аккаунтом, во избежание.

Comment: @andreycha спасибо, а как насчёт кривой безье?  )))

Comment: Ну нет же ничего проще. Открываете code-behind и переписываете один в один.

Comment: Должна быть возможность объединения аккаунтов

Comment: Объединить аккаунты вообще-то тоже можно: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var path = new Path()
{
    Stroke = Brushes.Black,
    StrokeThickness = 10,
    Data = new PathGeometry()
    {
        Figures =
        {
            new PathFigure()
            {
                StartPoint = new Point(100, 80),
                Segments =
                {
                    new PolyBezierSegment()
                    {
                        Points =
                        {
                            new Point(90, 200),
                            new Point(140, 200),
                            new Point(160, 200),
                            new Point(180, 200),
                            new Point(430, 190),
                            new Point(430, 280),
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```